# Angular 1.x image upload with custom attributes

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.x to provide a multiple file upload feature via a drag and drop interface. I want to seed one of the images as a default using a flag.

I am using a FormData object which will be passed to my backend to be saved. This is the structure of the data before I push the images to the object:

```
listing_images: Array(3)
     0: File
          default_image: 1
          lastModified: 1521848990788
          lastModifiedDate: Fri Mar 23 2018 23:49:50 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) {}
          name: "002.JPG"
          preview: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4f8ERXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg"
          size: 136276
          type: "image/jpeg"
          webkitRelativePath: ""
          __proto__: File
     1: File ....
```

The snippet shows one of the 3 images which are to be uploaded - the first of which has the default_image flag set to be true, so far so good.

I then use the append() function to add the images to my formData:

```
 var dataObj = new FormData();
 angular.forEach(listing_images, function(key, value) {
      dataObj.set(listing_images[key], value);
 });
```

If I loop the entries() of the dataObj I see:

```
listing_images[0], [object File]
listing_images[1], [object File]
listing_images[2], [object File]
```

So all looks good, then on my backend after submitting the dataObj if I debug the request data I see this format for each image:

```
'tmp_name' => '\tmp\php82C1.tmp',
'error' => (int) 0,
'name' => '002.JPG',
'type' => 'image/jpeg',
'size' => '136276',
```

As can be seen, the default_image flag has been lost. Is there a way to retain the custom values which i have pushed to the file object?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [FormData specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) you can see that `FormData` values can be either `USVStringBlob` or `File`/`Blob`. So, you cannot send whatever you want object (unless you convert it to some string and parse on the server-side in an appropriate way).

If you need to send `default_image` property you should send it as an additional parameter. Smth like this, I think:

```
 var dataObj = new FormData();
 angular.forEach(listing_images, function(key, value) {
      if (value.default_image) {
          dataObj.set('default_image', key);
      }
      dataObj.set(listing_images[key], value);
 });
```

Comment: are you suggesting to send it as an additional prarameter and then assign it to the listing_images on the backend? That is what I am doing currently and what I wanted to do. I was hoping to to just send the object to the backend in the correct format ready to save. Perhaps I have no other choice though?

Comment: You can't send objects via FormData unless you convert them to JSON string. However, you cannot mix them with files in the same field anycase, so you should use another field for additional params. 
But let's wait for some other answers, maybe I miss smth and some better solution could be proposed.